# Having to tap FlatList twice to activate the TouchableOpacity within the row

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with the following code. It seems that I have to tap the FlatView twice to get it to select the row. The first time it removes the keyboard and then the second time actually activates the TouchableOpacity. Can anyone see what the issue might be, Thanks.

```
render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    console.log("Rendering");

    if(this.state.inputText != ""){
        var contactListView = <View style={styles.contactListWrapper}>
            <FlatList
                data = {this.state.dataContactList}
                renderItem={({item}) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.pressRowContact( item )} >
                <View style={styles.contactRow}>
                    <View style={styles.standardProfilePicWrapper}>
                        <Image source={require('../../images/demo/Profile/sample2.jpg')} style={{width: 30, height: 30}}/>
                    </View>
                    <Text>Someone Name Here</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>}
            />
        </View>
    }else {
        var contactListView;
    }


    var selectedUsers = this.state.arrayContactsSelected.map(function(item) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addedContactNameWrapper} onPress={() => this.onAddedContactPress("")} key={item.userID} >
                <Text style={styles.contactSelectedName} >Oliver Rice</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
     });


    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{flex: 1}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <StatusBar hidden={true} />
            <View style={styles.headerBar}>
                <NavBar navigation={this.props.navigation} goBack={this.goBack} title="NEW MESSAGE" backButton={true} />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
                <View style={styles.addContactWrapper} >
                    <View style={styles.addContactLeft} >
                        <Text style={styles.contactTo}>To:</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.addContactRight} >
                        {selectedUsers}
                        <View style={styles.addedContactInputWrapper}  >
                            <TextInput
                            style={styles.addContactInput}
                            onChangeText={this.onChangeTextHandler}
                            value={this.state.inputText}
                          />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.mainContentWrapper} >
                    {contactListView}
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.inputTextMainMessage}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }

pressRowContact( rowSelected ){

var found = false;

for(var i = 0; i < this.state.arrayContactsSelected.length; i++) {
    if (this.state.arrayContactsSelected[i].userID == rowSelected.userID) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(found == false){

    var arrayContacts = this.state.arrayContactsSelected.slice()

    arrayContacts.push(rowSelected)

    console.log(arrayContacts)

    this.setState({
        inputText: "",
        arrayContactsSelected: arrayContacts
        });

}else {

    this.setState({
        inputText: "",
        });

}

}
```

Comment: we are having this same problem. Did you figure out why this was happening?  Any help would be appreciated.